# How to open GUI application on Windows via SSH if no active user sessions?

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-access, openssh, rdp

I am working on a project where I need to run a few tests through SSH using an interactive GUI application on multiple Windows VMs. I have seen various other solutions here for launching the GUI application such as with psexec or running schtasks and a .bat file. I have tried all of that. Unfortunately, the only time the GUI opens is when there is an active user session. For example, if I do something like `psexec -i 22 path\to\bat\file` it will launch the GUI with my active RDP session. This will still work while I am disconnected, as the user session is still active. However, if I log out of the user session entirely and try the same (either with psexec or directly running a bat with schtask), it won't work. It will simply run the GUI application as a background process, as when I login again with RDP, the GUI isn’t present and it only shows as a background process in the task manager.

Is there a way to trigger an RDP or some GUI style user session to become active in a headless manner? If not, then is there a different way to execute my application, where the interactive GUI is available with SSH or other means of headless connection when there is no active user signed in?

The Windows VMs have OpenSSH server running for connections.

Answer (score 0):

This question actually solved the other half of the puzzle for me, namely how to get SSH connections to use the interactive session. Here's how to keep an active interactive session open at all times. Note that depending on your use case you might explicitly need a multi-session windows installation, which is a different VM image in Azure for example.

1. Have the user you want these commands to run in log on automatically when windows boots. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon
2. Create a .bat file with the following contents somewhere (for me it's just on C:) `tscon 1 /dest:console`
3. In task scheduler, create a task that runs this bat file whenever a remote user disconnects.

Point 2-3 are not necessary if you never RDP into the autologon user. Whenever you RDP to this user, the console session moves from the autologon session to your RDP session, and this script just reattaches the console session back when you disconnect. This way, that user always has the console attached and thus has GUI available.